# Why do I see this pattern of enumerating many methods for 1,2,3, etc arguments followed by a general arbitrary size list of arguments?

Tags: java, design-patterns

[ImmutableList](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.java?r=80) is one example of what I'm talking about.  There's a series of methods accepting a fixed number of arguments followed by a general catch all signature

```
  public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E element) {
    return new RegularImmutableList<E>(copyIntoArray(element));
  }

  public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E e1, E e2) {
    return new RegularImmutableList<E>(copyIntoArray(e1, e2));
  }

  public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3) {
    return new RegularImmutableList<E>(copyIntoArray(e1, e2, e3));
  }

  public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4) {
    return new RegularImmutableList<E>(copyIntoArray(e1, e2, e3, e4));
  }

  public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5) {
    return new RegularImmutableList<E>(copyIntoArray(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5));
  }

  public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E... elements) {
    return (elements.length == 0)
        ? ImmutableList.<E>of()
        : new RegularImmutableList<E>(copyIntoArray(elements));
  }
```

(Comments removed for brevity).

Why not include just the final catch all (E... elements).   I'm guessing the answer is something along the lines of "optimization" but I'm not really clear why.  Is the check and branch for elements.length==0 really considered that costly?

Why stop at just 5 argument signatures, why not 10 or 50?

Is the reasoning something specific to Java or something that would apply to other compiled languages as well?

Comment: Looks like it is a dupe to me, those answer things.